# Как правильно задавать вопрос новичку, чтобы не получить толпу минусов

Tags: обсуждение, новые-участники

Рассмотрим пример: [Выдает ошибку, почему?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32585/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83?) Естественно, предположим, человек прочел [ЧаВо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/faq/).
Если не прочел, читаем:
[конкретную статью](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_8123.html)

PHP: для начала, откройте исходный код страницы и найдите все строчки, которые начинаются с

- Warning:
- Error:
- Fatal Error:
- Notice:

Если вы не знаете английского, ищите кусок

> "/YYYY.php on line XXX",

где XXX - любое целое число. Это - номер строки с ошибкой, а YYYY.php - имя вашего файла, в котором и происходит ошибка. Открываем файл, ищем нужную строку и смотрим на явные ошибки, вроде непроставленного; или незакрытой скобки. Далее, копируем все сообщение в гугл-переводчик и пробуем его понять. Если совсем-совсем непонятно, забиваем в гугл в виде:

> "Ошибка Fatal error: Call to undefined function что означает"

Все сообщение об ошибке копировать НЕ надо почти всегда. Если там нет ответа в первых двух позициях, то шлем на хэшкод это сообщение об ошибке и кусок текста вашего файла: строку, вызвавшую ошибку, строку до и строку после.

Снабдите комментариями, вроде, "переменная $foo извлекается из БД".

Comment: Поиском они все равно не пользуются)

Comment: > Естественно, предположим, человек прочел ЧаВо.

Это как раз неестественно :)

Comment: @Sh4dow, и другие темы тоже не читают. А те, кто читают, обычно умеют самостоятельно отлавливать банальные ошибки.

Comment: @ling, Что же делать? всех не перебьешь, да и надо же им как-то учиться.

Comment: @knes, думаю, нормальный поиск схожих тем мог бы помочь. Сейчас при заполнении заголовка вопроса идет поиск по полному соответствию фразе ("ошибка почему" не равно "почему ошибка"), а хорошо было бы иметь усложненный вариант поиска, с релевантностью и прочими фишками.

Comment: А можно, как это иногда делается но вопросных сервисах, так:
после того, как форму вопроса заполнили, сразу вопрос не создавать, а принудительно дать выдачу поиска по этой теме. И если уже посетитель настойчиво тычет «Создать» второй раз, тогда уже только аппрувить вопрос.

Comment: Плюсую усложнение поиска при вводе.

Comment: @Sh4dow, не судьба. Русские очки уже второй день ставят. =)

Comment: Второй день - не так уж и много) Ну и не думаю, что это прям мажорная проблема, чтоб ее сразу бежать и решать)

Comment: Для того чтобы вставить вместо числа - функцию - очень много. =)

Comment: согласен с предыдущим оратором. при создании вопроса можно вывести вопросы схожие с его заголовком сначала и потом уже если ему необходимо создать вопрос то создавать по второму тырканью создания. хотя бы не будет пустых вопросов аля - что почитать по пхп и так далее

Comment: Несмотря на всю его полезность, строго говоря, этот пост не является вопросом.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Но исследований тогда еще не было. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот еще полезные рекомендации: [Eric Steven Raymond, Как правильно задавать вопросы](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html)

Answer (score -1):

Еще предлагаю злостно минусовать тех кто отвечает на такие вопросы, чтобы вопросы такого характера не находили ответов никогда. готов чуть посливать карму ради такого дела.

Comment: Зачем? Можно просто не отвечать - специалисты рано или поздно забьют на юзеров, задающих такие вопросы, и вопрос не получит вменяемого ответа.

Comment: Всегда будут охотящиеся за кармой, поэтому лучше наказывать, чем ничего не делать. Да у этого варианта есть минусы, но есть и достоинства.

Comment: Даже у охотников за кармой есть нервы, которые рано или поздно дадут о себе знать. =) Плюс, это - хорошая антистрессовая практика. Вот вам хватит терпения лопатить страничный код, а потом иметь дело с неадекватом? Можете проверить. =)

Comment: Откуда столько зла? На англоязычном стэке нет такого....

Comment: @WalterNuss Там зло есть, и его в 10 раз больше чем на ruSo. Поверьте.

Comment: Я не согласен. Некоторые могут подумать, что вопрос хороший, писать ответ полчаса, а потом минусы?