# Альтернативный регламент для инициатив

Tags: предложение

Раз уж некоторым так хочется ввести регламент для инициатив, я предлагаю альтернативный его вариант. Есть [комментарий Николаса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6876/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2/6877?noredirect=1#comment27340_6877), в котором он перечисляет некие проблемы, однако, я с их наличием как-то не согласен, зато вижу другие. В любом случае я постараюсь отметить соответствующие факты в этом предложении.

**Тем, кому лень читать предпосылки, можно промотать часть вопроса до непосредственно предлагаемого регламента.** Помимо этого, во всех списках первая строка (или предложение) - это утверждение, а последующие - пояснение, что оно значит и почему именно так. Я действительно старался сделать этот пост удобочитаемым и лёгким для просмотра, хотя он и вышел очень длинным ^_^

---

Начнём с того, что же такое *правило* и что заставляет пользователей соблюдать правила.

Ни один новый пользователь не будет вычитывать сотни страниц правил перед тем как задать свой первый вопрос. Да и не все старые пользователи читали все обсуждения на мете. А как же тогда все следуют правилам, которых не знают?

На самом деле сообщество держится на нескольких **основных принципах** и комфортности для участников. Пожалуй, я бы выделил такие:

1. Мы программисты, администраторы или просто интересуемся компьютером.
   Это даёт тематику ресурса и вопросы, которые нам интересно обсуждать
2. Мы дружелюбны.
   Благодаря этому участники не разбегаются отсюда.
3. Здесь мало постороннего шума.
   Из-за раздражающих факторов люди могут разбежаться - поэтому мы хотим, чтобы разбежались те, кто создаёт шум, а более полезные участники остались.
   Мы никого не прогоняем, но те, кому некомфортно уйдут сами.
4. Некий шум всё же нужен.
   Когда всё однообразно, становится скучно. Нужен баланс, при котором мы можем над чем-то посмеяться или поучаствовать в каком-то соревновании, и это не будет раздражать и мешать основной цели.

В каких случаях **нужны специфические правила** помимо общих принципов?

1. Если цели сайта расходятся с целями конкретных участников.
   Яркий пример: [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/178988)
2. Если человек не понимает, как задавать вопросы.
   Пример: [Как правильно задавать вопрос новичку, чтобы не получить толпу минусов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/731/178988)
3. Если какой-то момент вызывает раздражение у значительной части участников.
   Примеры:
   - [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: "опросники" должны умереть!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/178988)
   - [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 2: "вопрос неясен" — это не MCVE/SSCCE!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1931/178988)
   - [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 3: “текст задачи” — это не отсутствие кода!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5953/178988)
   - [Причина "Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи" применяется не так, как задумывалась изначально](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/178988)
4. Если большинство нейтрально относится к какой-то теме (в том смысле, что она их и не радует, но и и не бесит), то когда она попадается на глаза, каждый действует в соответствии со своими представлениями. В таких случаях получается шатание в разные стороны и тому, на кого направлены рандомные разрозненные действия становится не очень комфортно. Такие ситуации устраняются принятием общих решений, которым потом следует большинство пользователей.
   Пример: [Опрос: Отношение сообщества к вопросам, затрагивающим этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/178988)
5. Если мы хотим узаконить нечто, что на данный момент не очень соответствует правилам сайта. Возможно, оно уже есть, возможно, мы лишь готовимся к этому. По сути это то же, что в прошлом пункте, только до того, как соответствующая проблема возникнет.
   Наиболее частые примеры - расширение тематики:
   - [Узаконим гольф?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/178988)
   - [Куй [железо], пока тематика сайта ещё обсуждается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1291/178988)
   - [Существование меток [поиск-библиотек], [поиск-программ] и т.п](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6367/178988)

Что важно для изменения правил?

- *Достаточное* внимание со стороны сообщества.
  Именно достаточное, а не чрезмерное. Под достаточным я понимаю такое, при котором принятое решение НЕ вызовет дискомфорта у большинства участников сообщества. Не важно, даны только 3 голоса голоса, или 33, если всех устраивает результат.
- Есть понимание *целей, результатов и последствий* введения правила.
  Нет смысла вводить новое правило просто ради правила. За ним всегда должна стоять какая-то цель. Например, в случае расширения тематики целью является "мне было бы интересно читать и отвечать на предлагаемую тему", а противопоставлением "меня бесят вопросы на эту тему на нашем сайте". *Противопоставление* - это некий здравый смысл, который крутится где-то в районе первого и третьего принципов. Пример: Я не хочу читать вопросы по животноводству. Животноводство не является объединяющим фактором для участников сайта. Участники уйдут, если сайт будет завален вопросами, не принадлежащими объединяющим их темам.
- Правила должны быть подкреплены *фактами.*
  Мы можем полгода в 100 человек думать, к чему же приведёт новое правило, и в итоге угадать или не угадать. А можем просто попробовать, увидеть реакцию от нескольких человек и всё понять за 3 дня. Второй путь предпочтителен, поскольку только он даёт верный результат. И он не навредит, поскольку мы можем (и даже должны) позволять некоторый уровень шума. *Аккуратно* поставили эксперимент, если провалился, зарыли тему и пошли дальше, если взлетело - радуемся и собираем плюсики на мете. Пример: [вопрос про тематичность социальной инженерии](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6769/178988) - можно долго обсуждать и гадать, а можно задать несколько вопросов и посмотреть, как на них отреагирует сообщество. А аккуратностью тут будет считаться число вопросов: пара вопросов за неделю - хорошо, по вопросу в день несколько дней - возможно, пара в день - не очень (давайте время, не заваливайте участников), забить всю главную страницу социальной инженерией - перебор и так делать не надо.
- Акцент должен делаться на *людях и целях,* а не на инструментах.
  [Ошибке молотка XY](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178988) могут быть подвержены не только технические вопросы, но и вопросы о правилах. Предлагая новое правило, человек стремится к чему-то и наша реакция должна быть направлена не на технику (конкретное предлагаемое правило), а на его проблему и цель. Возможно, мы можем предложить более хорошее правило, либо решить проблему как-то иначе.
- Участие в обсуждении должно быть *комфортным,* а именно:

  - надо минимизировать число обсуждений в *активной фазе*.
    Обсуждение требует много времени на чтение, обдумывание и, иногда, написание ответа. [Не стоит](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4343/178988) держать одновременно несколько обсуждений *в активной фазе*. Под активной фазой я понимаю свежее обсуждение, вызвавшее резонанс, либо старое обсуждение, ставшее актуальным в связи с новыми обстоятельствами. Большинство активных действий происходят в первые несколько дней, максимум неделю после публикации. Мы можем ещё месяц или больше продолжать собирать голоса, но фактически это голоса от прозевавших момент и они нечасто будут вдруг выявлять что-то новое, что перевернёт всё с ног на голову и вернёт обсуждение в активную фазу.
    Пример: только этот ответ я пишу уже 2 часа, а написал примерно половину (а был ещё [ответ в соседней теме](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6877/178988) и длинное обсуждение в модераторском чате) - я не могу тратить по столько времени на несколько одновременных обсуждений - даже на одно-то сложно!
  - нужна сосредоточенность *в одном месте*.
    Не надо беспричинно размазывать обсуждение на несколько тем, в том числе не надо разделять голосование за решение и голосование при обсуждении. Пример того, как НЕ надо делать: [оригинальное предложение](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6769/178988) => [оно же, но переформулированное](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6842/178988) => *а теперь проголосуем за него же* (по регламенту Николаса должно появиться через 2 недели). Вот чем эти вопросы различаются? Мусолим один вопрос, размазывая его по трём обсуждениям, причём абсолютно беспричинно.
    Конечно же, в случаях, когда вопрос другой или затрагивает отдельный нюанс, надо создавать новую тему. Но это как раз когда причины есть. А просто так - ну нет, не надо. Чем проще, тем лучше.

Что должно дать принятие регламента по созданию правил?

- Понимание, когда правило принято, а когда - нет.
  С момента принятия правила его можно показывать другим участникам с просьбой ему следовать. Было бы довольно странно просить участников следовать правилу, которое ещё не принято.
- Наличие рекомендованной схемы, приводящей к наиболее эффективному результату.
  Регламент даёт понимание, как следует действовать. Например, кому-то хочется расширить тематику, но он не понимает, как. А тут раз и готовый список с шагами!

Уж не знаю, какой из этого пункта плюс, но чую, что без регламента мы от этого вопроса не отделаемся...

---

## Что насчёт изменения правил?

Я намеренно хочу оставить этот момент за рамками текущего вопроса.

На данный момент есть два варианта действий:

- замораживать вопрос с принятым решением, а при желании это решение изменить, создавать новый вопрос и начинать с нуля
- позволять голосовать там же и таким образом позволять правилу меняться

У обоих вариантов есть свои плюсы и минусы, они заслуживают обсуждения в отдельном вопросе. Но этот вопрос я пока предлагаю отложить, чтобы не создавать несколько активных обсуждений одновременно.

---

PS: На написание этого вопроса понадобилось более 4 часов чистого времени.

Answer (score 5):

## История вопроса

Для понимания происходящего необходимо вернуться к тому, вследствие чего нам вообще понадобились какие–то дополнительные правила.

В [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42474958#42474958) был поднят вопрос, породивший дискуссию:

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, являются ли вопросы/ответы Меты правилами использования данного ресурса, и если да, каким образом трактуются противоречащие друг-другу ответы (выбирается с наибольшем количеством голосов?).

Также был задан вопрос на Мете: «[Является ли Мета набором правил, обязательных к исполнению?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6735/6)». Все же если посмотреть на проблему внимательно, у нас отсутствовали какие–либо процессы, позволяющие отделить вопрос–правило от вопроса–дискуссии на Мете, так как ранее вопросами организации в основном занимались несколько участников, которые имели более или менее одинаковые взгляды на проблемы.

Там же была высказана идея исторической блокировки:

> Мне кажется, с сего момента надо использовать историческую блокировку и только такие вопросы в будущем считать «закрепленными правилами». Сейчас, конечно, так делать нельзя, ибо большинство решений не имеют блокировку.

И ответ:

> Хорошая идея. В любом случае, если кто-то захочет изменить правила, он должен открыть новый вопрос.

Диалог [закончился подведением итогов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42479508#42479508) текущего состояния дел, где, по сути, были высказаны все основные [идеи будущей публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835).

## Почему это вообще важно?

Когда происходит конфликт интересов участников, обычно люди обращаются к правилам сообщества, чтобы понять, как на самом деле следует поступать. Правила сообщества можно поделить на основополагающие, которые закреплены в [справочном центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), и общественные, которые являются консенсусом сообщества, такие вопросы находятся на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Проблема проявляется в том, что не очевидно, что можно считать консенсусом и когда он достигнут. К примеру, представим, что кому–то что–то не нравится и он идет и выражает это в весьма узко поставленном вопросе на Мете, который не подразумевает альтернативных мнений и голосования как такового по определению. Вопрос: может ли далее участник ссылаться на такой вопрос и говорить о достигнутом «консенсусе» сообщества? Если нет, то как отделить вопросы, которые действительно получили одобрения, от тех вопросов, которые по большому счету прошли где–то в фоне?

Другая проблема — изменение решения во времени. Представим, что сегодняшняя активная аудитория решает, что надо все метки иметь в единственном числе. Мы собираемся на Мете, голосуем, увидим согласие и причины такого решения. Далее потратим тонну времени на приведение всех синонимов к одному виду. Но по прошествии квартала или двух альтернативный вариант набирает на один голос больше предыдущего лидера! Все зазря, все переделывать по–новой. Стойте! Что если мнение опять поменяется в течение месяца, опять идти и все менять? И так каждый месяц? (Одним из решений виделась историческая блокировка, не позволяющая изменять распределение голосов.)

Еще одна крайне волнующая меня проблема — предвзятые формулировки вопросов, которые могут быть составлены в виде «заманухи» или провокации либо сразу же содержат позицию автора вместо рассмотрения проблемы. Такие вопросы, по сути, блокируют свободное непредвзятое рассмотрение и заводят дискуссию в строгие рамки логического тупика. Нам бы все–таки хотелось принимать рациональные взвешенные решения, которые основаны не на способности участников красиво и складно писать (что, конечно же, очень важно!), а на логике и исходя из результирующей пользы для большинства участников.

## Что было предложено?

Как мне казалось, можно было попробовать задать какие–то требования для вопросов, которые призваны стать правилами, сделав их максимально развернутыми, нейтральными в формулировке и направленными на решения конкретных проблем. Результат — [руководство по составлению вопросов–инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/). Как стало видно из [обсуждения на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6876/), данный подход имеет несколько серьезных недостатков, которые, на самом деле, могут и не помешать вовсе, а могут все испортить. Если есть право полагать, что что–то пойдет не так, то оно действительно пойдет не так. На мой взгляд, инициативу с жесткими критериями следует отозвать, а вопрос переписать в формате общечеловеческих рекомендаций участникам: разделять проблему и взгляд на ее решение, следовать принципу «не навреди», детально рассматривать саму проблему в формулировке вопроса — все это отличные рекомендации для начала плодовитого обсуждения.

## Что предлагается сейчас?

В ходе обсуждения стало очевидно, что мы ищем решение какой–то общей проблемы организации сообществ, которая должна была бы уже быть решенной задолго до нас. Ниже я привожу результат дискуссии с коллегами. Описанный подход, как я его понял, действует на всех сайтах Stack Exchange и, вероятно, будет отличной отправной точкой и для нас.

### Предлагаемый подход

Прежде всего следует разделить вопросы на два типа: (1) вопросы управления сайтом и сообществом; (2) вопросы нововведений и изменений. Нам интересны только вопросы управления сайтом. Такие вопросы можно поделить опять же на два типа:

- Вопросы, *решения в которых принимают участники* демократически.
- Вопросы, *решения в которых принимает компания* единолично, опираясь на отзывы сообщества.

Провести черту между этими понятиями крайне сложно. Например, тематика сайта — это определенно вопрос, который не может быть рассмотрен кем–либо, кроме самих участников сообщества. С другой стороны, список возможных тематик ограничен: Stack Overflow о программировании — он может включать вопросы про администрирование, но вопросы готовки на сайте рассматривать не будут.

#### Почему вообще компания что–то должна решать, если сайт управляется сообществом?

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что сайт был создан с определенной миссией: собрать свободную базу знаний прикладных вопросов по программированию. Если что–то идет вразрез с этой миссией, инициатива будет отклонена компанией. Stack Overflow сегодня — это повседневный инструмент разработчика для решения прикладных вопросов (мы используем молоток для забивания гвоздей, но мы не едим им суп, не носим на голове, когда холодно, для этих целей у нас есть другие вещи). Помимо миссии, идущей под номером ноль, у нас есть ряд целей, например, создать сплоченное сообщество разработчиков. Любые инициативы, принимаемые в сообществе, должны так или иначе коррелировать с целями и миссией проекта. Например, предложение деанонимизировать голосование вряд ли получит реализацию, так как это решение может привести, как минимум, к отсутствию желания голосовать. Компания опять же отклонит данное предложение, исходя из опыта развития сообществ.

Важно отметить, что если какое–либо предложение невозможно реализовать сейчас (особенно техническое), это не значит, что его будет невозможно реализовать в будущем: публиковать вопросы–предложения в любом случае стоит!

#### Зачем обсуждать вопросы на Мете и что есть результат обсуждения?

Главная ошибка, которую мы допустили, рассматривая вопрос введения процессов: мы хотели задать четкие критерии того, какие вопросы–обсуждения на Мете считать правилами на основе выбора сообщества. Мы возвели формальный результат (количество голосов) в абсолют. Что в корне не верно, ведь нам важно достигнуть консенсуса по вопросам управления сообществом, а не какого–либо числового порога! Вот что действительно важно:

- Дискуссия о правилах важна и нужна сама по себе. Через диалог мы узнаем что–то новое для себя и, бывает, меняем точку зрения на противоположную.
- Важны логические выкладки и утверждения в ответах, а не количество голосов «за». **Для нас крайне важно понимать, почему это решение популярно, а не то, что оно популярно.**
- Голосование необходимо самому сообществу, чтобы посмотреть, какие идеи наиболее поддерживаемые в данный момент (сортировка по аналогии с основным сайтом).

[Принимать решение о чем–либо на основе распределения голосов считается в корне неверным](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177565/274323). Никто не знает, как и почему участники голосуют именно так, а не иначе: то ли поддерживают активиста как такового, то ли видят данное решение лучшим из имеющихся, то ли потому, что не поняли, что от них требуется и как надо голосовать. Понятие «решение *принято* большинством голосов» не применимо на сайтах Stack Exchange как минимум к правилам сообщества. Мы за «решение принято на основе доводов участников в проведенной дискуссии, консенсус в следующем...». Сообщество рассматривает проблемы и подходы к ним, пытаясь сделать это как можно глубже и детальнее. Сотрудники компании просматривают и/или участвуют в обсуждениях и на основе наиболее здравых замечаний обновляют правила сообщества в справочном центре или публикуют ответ с пояснением текущей реализации прямо к вопросу–обсуждению, если такой ответ предполагается и проблема получила како–либо решение. Пожалуйста, заметьте, что ответы вида «Я против. Голосуйте здесь, если ты против.» не просто не рассматриваются, а удаляются как вредоносный шум. Повторюсь: *для нас важно понять, почему это решение популярно, а не то, что оно популярно*.

#### Детальное обсуждение правил сообщества — цель в себе

Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы с пояснением тех аспектов, которые вас не устраивают, или того, что вы хотите улучшить. Публикуйте развернутое видение и обоснование лучшего, на ваш взгляд, решения. *Убедительность и основательность* — главный фактор принятия решения в реализацию, а не распределение голосов! Замечу, что зачастую эти вещи пересекаются: наиболее убедительный и обоснованный ответ получает максимальное количество голосов «за». Пожалуйста, не забывайте голосовать против односложных, ничем не подтвержденных высказываний, как бы вы не относились к самой инициативе. Такие ответы не нужны и лишь вводят в заблуждение.

Более подробно об идеях подхода можно найти в публикации «[Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/)», а также в вопросе «[How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177550/how-is-consensus-determined-on-meta-sites)».

Comment: Относительно раздела "История вопроса" - т.е. обсуждение вопроса велось исключительно в чате? и там же были в узком кругу "приняты" некие правила? А зачем нам тогда мета?

Comment: @PashaPash Был вопрос на Мете от Abyx и обсуждение в чате, по результатам которого я написал вопрос на Мете. Подскажите, что было сделано не так?

Comment: меня очень смущает идея обсуждать изменения глобальных, обязательных для исполнения правил, в чате, а не на мете.

Comment: Спасибо за интересную историю, но я не очень понимаю, каким образом она отвечает на вопрос. Что именно предлагается в этом ответе? _"Важны логические выкладки и утверждения в ответах"_ - для кого? _"решение принято на основе"_ - кем принято?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если в двух словах. Задача компании реализовать миссию по созданию свободной базы знаний. Компания утверждает, что без мыслей сообщества это сделать невозможно. Для сбора мыслей и отзывов была запущена Мета. На Мете те участники, кто заинтересован в сообществе больше остальных, высказывают свои идеи и мысли по процессам и нововведениям. Компания, исходя из имеющихся ресурсов и доводов за и против садится и делает. Решения принимаются ответственными сотрудниками компании. В своих ответах убеждать в правильности подхода следует все сообщество.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, _"Решения принимаются ответственными сотрудниками компании"_ - опять пришли к тому же?

Comment: Подчеркну, компания действует исходя из интересов сообщества, накопленного опыта развития сообществ, имеющихся в наличии очень ограниченных ресурсов и миссии проекта. Если очевидно, что достигнут консенсус по какому–либо вопросу, у компании есть ресурсы и реализация «не порушит» сообщество, то рано или поздно вопрос получит решение.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, _"Если очевидно, что достигнут консенсус по какому–либо вопросу"_ - критерии будут? В ответе утверждается, что голоса - это НЕ критерии. Тогда что же? Личное мнение сотрудника компании?

Comment: @Qwertiy Это то, как работают процессы на платформе Stack Exchange. Заметьте, мы не перенимали эти правила по умолчанию, мы прошли свой путь проб и обсуждений. Очевидно, что платформа в текущем виде дает такую гибкость, которая сводит на нет голосований ([отражено в ответе Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177565/274323)). Мы также видим, что ответы вида «Я не согласен. Против» полностью бесполезны и не нужны ([смотрите комментарии к вопросу про СИ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6842/), когда было лишь два ответа: один «За», другой «Против»).

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, критериев нет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, наличие гибкости никак не отражает реальную ситуацию. "Гибкость" мира позволяет пойти и прыгнуть с крыши, но ведь мы не говорим что мир слишком гибкий и с ним что-то не так? Поведение людей не обуславливается потенциальной гибкостью системы, а обуславливается их желанием. Ответы Да/Нет нужны, когда причины уже описаны в вопросе. В остальных случаях они тоже показательны, но отражают исключительно мнение и взгляды голосующего, который может не видеть полную картину.

Comment: @Qwertiy *опять пришли к тому же?* — подскажите, к чему мы вернулись? То есть у нас был четкий процесс: написали вопрос, опубликовались ответы, мы все проголосовали. Но некоторые участник начали «хакать» систему то проводя голосование тремя участниками, то в другой раз мы принимали решение за три дня и требовали его немедленной реализации, в иных случаях использовались формулировки, которые противоречит идеи свободных обсуждений. Я попытался регламентировать процессы так, чтобы «хаков» более не было и все инициативы были в равной позиции.

Comment: То есть ранее мы принимали все решения исключительно на основе распределения голосов. Предложенные процессы вызвали критику, в том числе не конструктивную. На основе отзывов стало ясно, что предлагаемые процессы сложны и если им может быть место, то надо менять что–то в самой системе, так как платформа в текущем виде крайне гибкая и все правила «устные». Получается, необходимо очень жестко следить за исполнением регламентов опять же сотрудникам компании, что физически не возможно из за лимита имеющихся в наличии ресурсов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, и это предложение сводилось к "сотрудник компании выбирает одну из инициатив раз в месяц и запускает по ней голосование". А этот ответ сводится к "сотрудник компании когда ему захочется выбирает инициативу, смотрит по ней аргументы сообщества и независимо от голосов сообщества принимает решение". Этот момент (помимо прочих) был расписан в ответе к соседнему вопросу, в этом же вопросе я предложил альтернативный путь принятия решений. Но по нему никаких комментариев не следует, по сути получается та же схема, которая была, только без регламента.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тяжело дискутировать, когда одна тема разнесена по двум вопросам (ровно по–этому вопрос и закрывался дубликатом). Пожалуйста, напомните предлагаемую вами схему. Я не понимаю о чем речь, в предыдущем вопросе критика проблем. Более того, опять же, опираясь на и на здравый смысл (смотрите распределение голосов в вопросе СИ), и на рекомендации основателей SO, итоговые решения в части вопросов принимает компания, так как она поддерживает вектор развития в сторону реализации исходной мисси проекта (почему, описано в блоге Джеффа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, [в соседнем ответе 10 пунктов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6897/178988). Если надо кратко, то достаточно прочитать первые предложения из всех пунктов списков.

Answer (score 1):

**Я концептуально согласен с предлагаемым регламентом,** хотя критерии стабильности (пункт 9), необходимость заморозки вопроса после принятия решения и порядок пересмотра принятого решения требуют дополнительного рассмотрения.

<sub>[этот ответ следует пункту 4 регламента - голосуем за ответы, а не за вопрос]</sub>

---

## Регламент

1. Для несрочных вопросов подождать, пока закончатся другие активные обсуждения.
   Участие в нескольких активных обсуждениях очень затратно по времени. Без веских причин не стоит создавать несколько активных обсуждений одновременно. Обращаю внимание, что активная фаза не равна времени сбора голосов, а обычно занимает от дня до недели - это только то время, пока участники активно переписываются (в комментариях или чате) на поднятую тему и публикуют ответы.
2. Задать вопрос с меткой [предложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) на мете в произвольной форме.
   В вопросе стоит описать, что именно предлагается сделать и какую пользу оно должно принести. При желании можно добавить в вопрос предлагаемое решение, либо опубликовать его отдельным ответом.
   Да, я понимаю, что предвзятая формулировка может влиять на результат обсуждения, но я против требования на "чистые" вопросы, в которых нет ничего кроме фактов и формулировки проблемы, поскольку это будет приводить к [ошибке XY](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178988). Формулировка вопроса всегда указывает на цель, с которой он задаётся.
3. Голоса на вопросе ничего не значат.
   Участники могут ставить голоса на вопрос по любому критерию ("о, спасибо за интересный вопрос", "наконец-то ты на мете", "да задолбал уже, вся главная твоими вопросами завалена").
4. Для принятия решения нужен ответ.
   Даже если этот ответ будет единственной фразой "Я согласен с решением из вопроса" или "Никакой проблемы нет, ничего делать не надо".
   Важно понимание того, за что именно даётся голос. Это не должны быть какие-то левые причины, влияющие на голоса на вопросе.
5. На вопрос могут публиковаться любые ответы, в том числе, что проблемы вообще нет, либо предлагаться другие решения, отличающиеся от предложенного в вопросе. Так же можно в ответах обсуждать предложенное решение и рассматривать плюсы и минусы различных вариантов.
6. Если предлагается что-то разрешить, нужен *эксперимент*.
   Например, для расширения тематики следует попробовать задать несколько соответствующих вопросов и посмотреть, как их воспримет сообщество. В принципе, это можно сделать и до вопроса, но тогда у них не будет защиты в виде обсуждения на мете. Если вопрос на мете уже есть, то можно первым комментарием к вопросу указать, что он задан как экспериментальный и дать ссылку на обсуждение предлагаемой тематики. Это решает сразу две задачи: во-первых, это привлечёт людей (причём именно заинтересовынных) к обсуждению и голосованию на мете, а во-вторых, поможет предотвратить преждевременное закрытие вопроса как оффтопика. Но не следует заваливать сайт такими вопросами: например, можно ограничиться одним вопросом в день в течение нескольких дней, или двумя в неделю - опять же стоит смотреть на то, насколько положительно их воспринимает сообщество. Если вопрос словил -17, то стоит подумать и не торопиться задавать следующий.
7. Кандидатами на решение могут быть только ответы, в которых что-то предлагается.
   Ну либо ответ, что вообще ничего делать не надо. Само собой, список плюсов или минусов решения из вопроса сам решением быть не может. Ответ должен быть конструктивным и явно выражать какой-то решение.
8. Галочка принятого ответа игнорируется.
   Хотя хорошим тоном было бы ставить галочку на принятое решение, решение принимается сообществом, а галочка ставится одним участником. Мы не хотим, чтобы один участник мог подменить мнение сообщества :)
9. Решение считается принятым, *когда обсуждение стабильно*.
   Под стабильностью решения понимается примерная стабильность распределения голосов по потенциальным решениям, отсутствие активного обсуждения и появления новых ответов.

   *Примеры (конкретные численные характеристики обсуждаются отдельно):*

   - Лидер по числу голосов, продержавшийся на первом месте неделю, за которую не появилось новых ответов.
   - В случае голосования <kbd>разрешить</kbd> / <kbd>запретить</kbd> - разрешить, если число вносящих изменение больше числа несогласных в полтора раза.

   Ещё раз подчёркиваю, что численные характеристики (в полтора раза, в 2 раза, в 10 раз, на одного; неделя, день, год) стоит обсуждать отдельно, здесь я предлагаю только концептуальную идею.
10. В любой момент при желании и/или необходимости модератор или менеджер сообщества может повесить на обсуждение метку [важное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5), чтобы привлечь дополнительное внимание сообщества.
    Лично я считаю, что большинство обсуждений может спокойно пройти без этой метки, но, несомненно, будут случаи, когда она понадобится.

## Этот ответ предназначен для концептуального обсуждения предлагаемого мною регламента.

- Все детали (типа сроков и числа голосов) можно обсудить отдельно.
- В данный момент интересует концептуальное отношения к предлагаемой схеме, её понятность и прозрачность. А так же её сравнение с [регламентом Николаса](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6836/178988).
- Так же принимаются различные пожелания и предложения.
- Можно в ответах высказывать своё мнение касательно других ответов с предложениями - это поможет сформировать окончательный вариант в случае появления полезных дополнений.
- Я постараюсь не изменять регламент в ответе, чтобы не инвалидировать результаты голосования и ответы.

Comment: Надо ещё понять кто и какие именно инициативы выставляет на принятие. Моё предложение, единым решением в чате в зависимости от актуальности и насущности темы в конкретный момент времени.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, сам участник в свободное (для сообщества) от активных обсуждений время. Или в любое время, если прям срочно надо. Или я твой комментарий не понял.

Comment: вы всё верно поняли. То есть согласованность с другими участниками на ответственность самого вопрошающего... могут быть коллизии по теме чьё предложение актуальней, если его можно будет самовольно выдвигать в ограниченную по числу очередь.. Либо делать одно основным, но выдвигать можно без ограничений, они идут просто как предложения до периода освобождения очереди.

Comment: можно тогда сделать так что предложений можно делать без ограничений, но то предложение которое обсуждается и решается сообществом в фазе принятия решение, уже фиксируется и оно одно, остальные ждут своей очереди и спокойно обсуждаются в естественном порядке.

Comment: >>  сам участник в свободное (для сообщества) от активных обсуждений время << тогда может получится кто первый предложил, тот и занял трон и слот в очереди.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, времени требует именно обсуждение, а не принятие решения. У нас сейчас нет кучи возможных инициатив. Чтобы произошла ситуация, которую ты описываешь, надо чтобы человек 5 одновременно вдруг захотели поменять правила, причём разные - это очень маловероятно. Если захотят двое - ну кто второй, тому придётся подождать от нескольких дней до недели - это не месяц из варианта Николаса - очередь не выстроится. Так что нет смысла решать проблемы, которые не возникнут.

Comment: В любом случае я думаю неразумно кто первый того и тапки.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, предлагай тогда. Ситуация: вот я пришёл и у меня есть инициатива. Завтра пришёл кто-то ещё и у него другая. Но ты этого сегодня ещё не знаешь, на данный момент есть только одна. Что надо? Спросить в чате? Ответ "да", потому что других кандидатов нет. Я не вижу проблемы, что тот, кто опоздал, подождёт неделю.

Comment: >> Для несрочных вопросов подождать, пока закончатся другие активные обсуждения << ну вот у меня есть предложение, а сейчас идёт другая тема и я жду пока она не пройдёт, потом она прошла и оказывается что кто-то ещё ждёт, и он выставит первым, и что мне опять ждать, а потом ещё кто-то влезет...? Своё предложение я уже сделал - предлагать в любой момент, но фокус делается на одно предложение, которое активно и рассматривается. В случае когда есть несколько вариантов куда сместить фокус, решать в чате в свободной форме. Обычно порядок очевиден, и это не вызовет проблем.

Comment: Например в данном случае актуальней обсуждение самого регламента, чем обсуждение расширения темы на Социальную Инженерию. Это очевидно.

Comment: Ну можно где-то в чате сказать, что ты следующий. Но реально у нас за всю историю не так уж много крупных обсуждений - такая ситуация в ближайшем времени не возникнет.

Comment: А, ясно. Я то думал что всё время такое и обсуждаете. Как я сюда пришёл всё время и обсуждали ))

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я последний на обсуждение, за мной просили не занимать!

Comment: _Даже если этот ответ будет единственной фразой_ — это идет в разрез с идеологией Stack Overflow. Представьте, что на вопросы по программированию мы бы отвечали «Я считаю надо так» и все. Кому вообще нужные такие ответы? *Для нас важно понять, почему это решение популярно, а не то, что оно популярно.*

Comment: _Если предлагается что-то разрешить, нужен эксперимент._ — это далеко не всегда верно. Более того, эксперимент возможен только в том случае, если сообщество пришло к консенсусу, что он нужен. Если консенсуса нет, проводить эксперименты не отвечающие правилам не следует. Каждый из нас имеет какой–то опыт, на основании которого мы можем считать так или иначе, но это не означает, что наши предположения верны. Идти в разрез с обоснованным мнением других участников не стоит. Самый простой эксперимент — мысленный. Проделайте его и поделитесь результатами в ответе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, _"Представьте, что на вопросы по программированию мы бы отвечали «Я считаю надо так» и все."_ - это говорилось про случай, когда решение и обоснование приведено в вопросе - всё уже есть, надо только соглашаться или не соглашаться не голосом за вопрос, а голосом за ответ, поэтому такой ответ и нужен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, _"Более того, эксперимент возможен только в том случае, если сообщество пришло к консенсусу, что он нужен"_ - почему? Откуда взялся консенсус, если ничего не обсуждали? Ну и если мысленный эксперимент проваливается, то может и идею предлагать не надо? Предполагается всё-таки, что предложения адекватные.