# Обновление интерфейса тревог комментария

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии

Новое всплывающее окно о причинах тревоги комментария:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Nicolas как может быть [завершено], если прямо сейчас оно на английском?

Comment: @alexolut, может быть, завершено - значит не требует дальнейших действий? Вероятно, Николаса смутил переведённый скриншот.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, почему [tag:статус-завершено], если сообщения по-прежнему на английском?

Comment: @Qwertiy переходим на самоуправление! снимай метку к чертям :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Строки [перевода](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/149840726?q=translated_after%3A2018-08-01+source_updated_before%3A2018-08-01) добавлены в Transifex:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем там точки на конце? Нужны ли они? Как правильно?

Comment: Они были в оригинале. Если их убрать - могут возникнуть коллизии, когда эти строки будут переиспользованы в другом месте.

Comment: Вечно всё у нас через ... коллизии. Разработчики еще не поняли, что **каждый** текстовый ресурс должен использоваться только в одном месте, если мы хотим нормальные локализованные сообщества...

Comment: А может `он` убрать?

Comment: Вот про убрать `It's - Он` я думал, да.. `Комментарий` там еле влезает, да и тавтология(строчкой ниже он уже есть)

Comment: Добавил предложения без "Он". Пусть @Aer разбирается ;)

Comment: При чём тут Aer? Раньше как раз и было без местоимения «он» (и, к слову, без точек в конце строки; причём безо всяких конфликтов).

Comment: Aer при том, что у меня нет права утверждать переводы. Раньше в оригинале не было ни точки, ни `It's`

Comment: "вы" пишем с маленькой. Для "flag" принят перевод "тревога", а не "сигнал". В остальном утвердил.

Comment: @alexolut, благодарю)

Comment: "Спасибо за установку тревоги" - показалось мне слишком машинным, что ли)

Comment: Что вы хотите от робота?

Comment: Я чуть-чуть доработал ваш перевод и оставил некоторые комментарии. Спасибо!

Comment: Нет, я никого не хотел задеть. Принципы, которыми я руководствуюсь, добавляя перевод, были описаны Николаем в одном из постов — решения о переводе не принимаются путем голосования. Если же у вас есть конкретные предложения, пойдемте обсудим их в чате — это всегда хорошо.

Comment: Сейчас я занят созданием скриншота с новыми правками, чтобы убедиться что ничего не поедет после "передёргивания" =)

Comment: Я уже проверил, ничего не поедет )

Comment: @Aer без голосования - не то же самое что и без обсуждения

Comment: @PavelMayorov кто от него уходит? Повторю: «Если же у вас есть конкретные предложения, пойдемте обсудим их в чате — это всегда хорошо».

Comment: @Aer, не могли бы вы поделиться тем постом?

Comment: @Aer предложения относительно чего? Лично я не вижу вашего варианта перевода, все что я знаю - то, что он чем-то отличается от показанного тут...

Comment: @vp_arth https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/232295

Comment: @PavelMayorov обновления частично доступны на скриншоте, см. пост выше

Comment: @Aer не вижу вас в истории изменений ответа. На этом скриншоте точно есть ваши изменения?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, смотрите внимательней. В любом случае высказать свои замечания вы можете в любое время.

Comment: @Aer как я могу понять что ваши изменения есть на скриншоте?

Comment: @Aer что же до того поста - разве вы являетесь представителем Администрации?

Comment: @PavelMayorov используйте интерфейс сайта, сравнивайте версии...

Comment: @PavelMayorov к чему ваш вопрос? Я не администратор.

Comment: @Aer к тому, что там не написано что переводчик может единолично что-то менять в уже сложившемся и устоявшемся переводе просто потому что ему так захотелось

Comment: @PavelMayorov если вам охота поговорить, пойдемте в чат. К внесенным изменениям я оставлял комментарии, читайте мои сообщения и пост Николая внимательней.

Comment: @Aer не вижу ваших комментариев. Пост Николая я читал.

Comment: @PavelMayorov они доступны всем переводчикам. Я не намерен продолжать разговор здесь, а не в чате.

Comment: @Aer а я не намерен обсуждать принципиальные вопросы в чате, где уже через неделю никто обсуждения не найдет.