# Перевод всплывающего тоста при тревоге

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Поиск по мете результатов не дал, по сему пишу.

При тревоге на комментарий (`невежливый или оскорбительный`) он удалился сразу (видимо, регулярка по `фрилансерам`) — справа появился зелёный тост с «извинениями», который я не успел заскринить. Текст был полностью на английском.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зелёный тост "thanks for flagging" был переведён в рамках [вопроса про popup](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7575/176064)

Comment: @vp_arth когда перевод вступит в силу?

Comment: Это технический момент, я думаю, что не раньше понедельника

Comment: @vp_arth мне теперь как поступить, удалить вопрос/закрыть самому или.. ?

Comment: Удалять не нужно, проблема в том вопросе не обозначена. Перенёс комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлены переводы:

> Thanks for flagging
>
> Спасибо за установку тревоги!

И:

> We're sorry you saw this abusive comment. Flags like yours help us maintain a kind, respectful community.
>
> Сожалеем, что вы увидели этот оскорбительный комментарий. Ваши тревоги помогают нам сохранять сообщество добрым и уважительным.

---

*Для появления перевода на сайте требуется некоторое время. Будьте терпеливы*

Comment: Я не уверен, но там текст был подлиннее (с извинениями и прочим). Оба варианта текста переведены?

Comment: Не стоит ставить зелёную галку.. `We're sorry you saw this abusive comment. Flags like yours help us maintain a kind, respectful community.` - это оно?

Comment: Скорее всего да, оно.

Comment: Плохо, что это сложно проверять) Надеюсь, не отхвачу бан за ложные тревоги)

Comment: Я верно подтвердил дубликат? Этот перевод в том числе исправляется тем вопросом?

Comment: Нет, эта строка не была переведена) Но это не так важно, в принципе.

Comment: "вы" с маленькой пишем в интерфейсе сайта.